# Is string_view really promoting use-after-free errors?

Tags: c++, dangling-pointer

According to an article ([here](https://alexgaynor.net/2019/apr/21/modern-c++-wont-save-us/) and [there](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/1038)) this code is an erroneous use-after free example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

int main() {
  std::string s = "Hellooooooooooooooo ";
  std::string_view sv = s + "World\n";
  std::cout << sv;
}
```

In the article it is stated that the `string` s will be freed when the `string_view` is used! This goes against my debugging experience. But I'm asking you to confirm/verify/check this.

In my experience, stack/scope variables are freed (calling the destructor would be a far more correct wording) at the exit of the scope. This means that in this case, this would happen AFTER the `std::cout << sv;`

However I have never used `string_view`, so I don't know about any internal mechanics of this object.

If indeed it is a dangerous behaviour, could you explain it?
Otherwise, I'd be glad to read the confirmation that scope variables destructors are called only at the exit of the current scope, naturally, or when an exception is thrown, interrupting the thread in the current scope.

---

**EDIT**:
After the first two answers, it is really a use-after-free usage.

Subsidiary question: Do you think we could add a move constructor with the delete keyword in the definition of string_view so as to forbid that?

Comment: The things is that the scope of unnamed temporary object created with `s + "World\n"` is limited to that one statement, not to the end of `main`.

Comment: Yes, `string::operator string_view` is a huge mistake. Why was it made applicable to rvalue references? Heads should be rolling.

Comment: @n.m. yes exactly, why does it accepts `rvalue` reference ? That's what I was wondering about after the interesting answers...  So as to prevent this, do you think we could add a move constructor with the delete keyword in the definition of string_view ?

Comment: @StephaneRolland I suspect the reason is that `std::string_view` is expected to be used as aa function parameter so that temporaries can be passed into a function (like with a const ref). Obviously the lifetine is fine for that scenario.

Comment: @Galik Yes this is a legit scenario, I retract my objection ;) But perhaps then string_view should *only* be used as a function parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with this code...

```
std::string_view sv = s + "World\n";
```

... is that `sv` is not set to `s` but to a nameless *temporary* created by the expression `s + "world\n"`. That *temporary* is destroyed immediately after the whole expression ends (at the semicolon).

So yes, this is a "use after free" type error.

If you want to extend the life of that *temporary* you have to assign it to a variable that will maintain it - like a new `std::string` object:

```
std::string sv = s + "World\n"; // copy the temporary to new storage in sv
```

A `std::string_view` is merely a "view" onto a string, it is not a string in itself. It is only valid as long as the string it "looks" at is valid.

There is another quirk here too. You can also bind the *temporary* to a `const` *reference* which extends the life of temporaries:

```
std::string const& sv = s + "World\n"; // just keep the temporary living
```

Why is initializing a `std::string_view` from a *temporary* allowed?

I can not speak for the standards committee, but my suspicion would be that  `std::string_view` is expected to be used as a function parameter so that temporaries can be passed into a function (like with a const ref). Obviously the lifetime is fine for that scenario.

If we forbade initialization from temporaries then a major use of `std::string_view` would be negated.  You would be forced to create a new `std::string` (or binding to a const ref) before calling a function making the process awkward.

Comment: `keep the temporary living` - that's one horrible thing to do

Comment: Okay. Had I known string_view was taking a pointer/reference as input, I might have sensed the danger. Thanks for the explanation: symptom + remedy. I agree that this is tricky / error prone.

Comment: @Galik Do you think we could add a move constructor with the delete keyword in the definition of string_view so as to forbid that?

Comment: @StephaneRolland I added some comments at the end.

Comment: @StephaneRolland No, the correct way is obvious, don't let there be an implicit conversion. This has been discussed 20 years ago on the conversion to `char*`, they are literally the same problem.

Comment: @PasserBy Not so obvious because it had not sparkled in my mind until you said it.  I like your proposal.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `s + “World\n”` results in a temporary object. The lifetime of this temporary `std::string` is just long enough to initialise `sv`. The memory that `sv` refers to is freed immediately after it is initialised (when the temporary object is destroyed).