# C++: What does a const reference to the return value of a function mean?

Tags: c++, c++14

Here's a snippet from my C++ code:

```cpp
std::queue<std::string> get_file_names(const std::string &indir)
{
    std::queue<std::string> file_names;

    fs::recursive_directory_iterator end;
    for (fs::recursive_directory_iterator it(indir); it != end; it++) {
        const std::string &extn = it->path().extension().string();
        if (extn == ".zip") {
            const std::string &file_name = it->path().string();
            file_names.push(file_name);
        }
    }

    return file_names;
}
```

Is it a good practice to make every string you won't modify a const reference? I have trouble understanding how can such a reference exist in this context at all. Like the return value of `it->path().string()` above. How can it be assigned to a reference that can be later used outside of the scope of the function when pushed back to a vector?

I feel like it has to do something with `std::move`.

Comment: if you push, it push a copy.

Comment: @ kenticent you should never store pointer to local (variable or reference) which can get out of scope and becomes invalidate. (unless the pointer is also only used in current scope)

Comment: oh and answer your question, yes you can store it (pointer to `const string&`) in `std::vector<const std::string*>`

Comment: @kenticent -- Stop worrying about this and write the code "naturally".  In this day and age of C++, even passing a string by value gets optimized by the compiler.

Comment: After all, `reference` is simply ***alias** to an already-existing item*

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code:

```
const std::string &file_name = it->path().string();
```

extends the lifetime of the temporary `std::string` returned by [`std::filesystem::path::string()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string). Since you've marked that as `const`, it can't be moved into `file_names`, it must be copied.  Assuming you want a move, you would write:

```
auto&& file_name = // ...
file_names.push(std::move(file_name));
```

Notice that [`std::queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) has a [`push()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/push) overload for r-value references.

Modern C++ provides a lot of opportunities for compilers to optimize, so avoiding questions/"confusion" about dangling references (the `auto&&` syntax is "new" in C++11) might be a better approach:

```
auto file_name = // ...
file_names.push(std::move(file_name));
```

Writing "natural" code that "looks and behaves like the `int`s" is often a good approach. In the unlikely situation you find that this is *really* a performance bottleneck, you can revisit; write your code for clarity first.

Comment: Sorry for responding late, but what will happen if we make `file_name` in the example you've provided just a reference? `auto& file_name = // ...
file_names.push(std::move(file_name));`

Answer (score 2):

No I wouldn't recommend to ever use `const std::string&`. If you want to have a viewer to a string then use `std::string_view` instead. `std::string_view` is not suitable only in the case with old C-style API where function accepts `const char*` as input without an option to submit its size; hopefully these APIs die out eventually. All decent API always add option to submit `const char*` coupled with its size as an additional option.

If you want a `std::string` then just use `std::string` or if you want to explicitly state that you don't intend to change it then just make it `const std::string`.

In your case as pointed by other answers, the returned object by the `path`'s method `.string()` is a `std::string` so capturing it as `const std::string&` explicitly is just non-sensical.

If you stored it as `std::string` then at least you could've moved it into the output `std::queue<std::string> file_names`.

Edit: about why old C-style strings aren't good and that length should be forwarded. Please check this article

https://nee.lv/2021/02/28/How-I-cut-GTA-Online-loading-times-by-70/

Turns out GTA's loading times very crazy slow (several minutes, 5-6 on average) because it was stuck computing `strlen` over and over again while reading a 10mb json file.

Comment: `std::string_view`s are very tricky because they are non-owning and don't track the lifetime. They should be avoided unless performance requires it.

Comment: @ Acorn that's a terrible advice. There is nothing tricky about using a non-owning objects. How using a `const std::string&` any better? It is also non-owning, except some declarations cases where it might be. Are you saying one should use only copies?

Comment: There are entire standards, companies, tools and even languages dedicated to this problem. A `const std::string &` is better for several reasons: it is explicit in the type system, it cannot be null, it works for any type, it only requires C++98 and it is well-known and supported. And yes, if a copy is enough, a copy should be used. We don't use copies everywhere because they are slow.

Comment: @Acorn `const std::string&` is equivalent to viewer and it cannot view properly. To pass a substring of type `const std::string&` you need to allocate new data. It makes `const std::string&` poor choice for any parsing. *There are entire standards, companies, tools and even languages dedicated to this problem.* you really exagerrate. You probably confuse completely different problems. There is nothing like that to deal with `string_view`.

Comment: @Acorn view is not a pointer. Reference to std::string doesn’t add anything that string_view cannot do.

Comment: "*view is not a pointer.*" But it is... :-)

Comment: @ALX23z well you simply cannot use `std::string_view` in OP's code.

Comment: and constness is always a topic, but not really that relevant here. (`string&&` vs `const string&`, note that you can also move the former)

Comment: @appleapple you should read the answer fully. It both answers the title question and the provided usecase.

Comment: yes as I point out string&& is also viable, and constness is another problem, maybe you can read my second comment fully first? @ALX23z

Comment: there is nothing wrong using `const string&` to catch a return value. and I think you don't really point out the downside of it (you can switch `std::string` with `string&&`, `const std::string` with `const std::string&` and all you say still hold). (or `auto&&`, ofcourse)

Comment: @appleapple then you don't understand the answer or even the context of it. While certain ways to write code might not be causing a bug doesn't mean that one should do it. It merely implies that the code does what it's supposed to do - it doesn't imply that it is a good way to write or that there is any good purpose for doing so. Also strange usages indicate a lack of understanding of what the hell the programmer was doing when writing the code.

Comment: @appleapple there are basic c++ guidelines that state that things should be written minimally, intention of programmer should be clear, and there should be a purpose behind writing a code in certain ways. What's the purpose of `std::vector<int>&& vec = ...`. When is it better than `std::vector<int> vec = ...`? only in cases when it is unknown whether returned value is a temporary or r-value reference and you don't want to trigger the move. This is a convoluted case possible only in templates and even then it is rare. So according to guidelines one should write with `&&` only in such odd cases.

Comment: @ALX23z it's not strange usage. ymmv. (do you omit `const string&` on purpose?)

Comment: @ALX23z btw, the minimally written ofcourse is not `string_view`, do you contradict to yourself? (nor `std::string`)

Answer (score 1):

### Explanations

> How can it be assigned to a reference that can be later used outside of the scope of the function **when pushed back to a vector**?

The variable `file_names` is of type `std::queue<std::string>` (and not `std::queue<std::string&>` - that is by the way not possible this way, but by using `std::reference_wrapper`). So it does not store "references to strings" but the actual "strings".

If you push a string reference, actually a copy of the referenced string will be pushed.

---

> Is it a good practice to make **every string you won't modify** a const reference?

Regarding "best practice" consider using [std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) in exchange for const string references (at least since C++17).

---

> I feel like it has to do something with `std::move`.

It does not. In this case it has something to do with the type argument of the `std::queue`.

### Bonus

You can store references within a (STL) container by using a [reference_wrapper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) as type argument.

Comment: I don't think `std::string_view` can be used here, the returned temporary is destroyed and you get invalid view.

Comment: `std::string_view` is far from best practice. It is a pitfall and I would avoid using it anywhere except as function parameters where performance matters.

Comment: @appleapple: I mentioned `std::string_view` in reference to the question "Is it a good practice to make every string you won't modify a const reference?", since the paragraph above answers the question "How can it be assigned to a reference that can be later used outside of the scope of the function when pushed back to a vector?". Perhaps I should clarify that in the answer also.

Comment: @Acorn: could you please provide some references supporting your "pitfall" thesis? I'm really curious about that.

Comment: @Chillip Sure, one from SO itself: [Is string_view really promoting use-after-free errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55790420/9305398) A view (and a span) is, after all, a pointer-size pair; so you must be as careful with views as with pointers. Or even more so, because they hide the fact they *are* a pointer.

Comment: @Acorn: despite the fact, that std::string_view is no pointer itself but (may) holds one ("A **typical implementation** holds only two members: a pointer to constant CharT and a size." - [[source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view)]), I do not share your opinion to discourage people from using it if they know how to handle it. [source] even notes: "It is the programmer's responsibility to ensure that std::string_view does not outlive the pointed-to character array". So if you know what you are doing - what you really should at all times - I do not see any problem here.

Comment: @Chilipp The C++ standard doesn't say how to implement types, that is a given and applies to everything (to the point it isn't useful to state it). `string_view`, like `span`, are pointer-size pairs in every reasonable implementation. The source you quote is explaining the obvious **because** it is a pitfall. Saying "*you need to know what you are doing*" is not useful to solve the issue.

Comment: Well, let's better end this discussion here. Since I initially wrote "consider using" anyway, I'm not insisting that one uses `string_view`, but to consider whether it seems useful. Furthermore, the actual question also involves other aspects - apart from our subject of disagreement.